# How To Schedule .NET Framework Compilation?

Tags: .net-framework, compile, decompile

Sometimes i find it annoying for .NET Framework start compilation of files without my authorization. I read somewhere that i can execute compilation when i want or maybe even schedule it. At least i would like .NET Framework to perform its task when computer is IDLE.

Comment: What did the place where you read about controlling it suggest?  What makes you think it's just spontaneously starting this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're talking about, it's the mscorsvw.exe service reporting 100% CPU usage spikes, during .NET pre-compiles, and you want it to do it only while the system is idle.

From [David Notario's WebLog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206071802/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/04/27/412838.aspx) "What is mscorsvw.exe and why is it eating up my CPU? What is this new CLR Optimization Service?":

> mscorsvw.exe is precompiling .NET assemblies in the background. Once it's done, it will go away. Typically, after you install the .NET Redist, *it will be done with the high priority assemblies in 5 to 10 minutes and then will wait until your computer is idle to process the low priority assemblies*. Once it does that it will shutdown and you won't see mscorsvw.exe. One important thing is that while you may see 100% CPU usage, the compilation happens in a process with low priority, so it tries not to steal the CPU for other stuff you are doing. Once everything is compiled, assemblies will now be able to share pages across different processes and warm start up will be typically much faster, so we're not throwing away your cycles.

So it should already do that.  You can visit that link, or do some basic searches for mscorsvw.exe, and you should find the information required to temporarily stop the process and/or service responsible for it.